# Fixed element with an overflowing-y, perspective parent

Tags: css, reactjs

So i have an issue here, I have this parent element named `home-page-wrapper`:

```
.home-page-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-y: auto; 
  perspective: 10px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d; 
}
```

and these child elements, wherein one is content itself while the other is a  background that is overflowing the parent element, which enables scrolling within the parent element, for parallax effect:

```
.home-page {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 65px;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  max-width: 100vw;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(2);
}
```

What im expecting is, when i scroll, i want my content element to be 'fixed' to my screen since i set that value to `position`, and my background to be scrolling along the flow at a different speed thanks to the perspective property. the scrolling speed is working but the issue is, my content element isn't fixed anymore. I've observed that when i comment out:

```
  overflow-y: auto; 
  perspective: 10px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

from the parent element or home-page-wrapper, my content works as it would normally, fixed. So like what i can understand is that those properties are the reason why my content element is acting as it should normally.

Comment: please share html also

Answer (score 0):

When you apply perspective and transform-style: preserve-3d to an element, it establishes a 3D rendering context for its child elements. This might interfere with the behavior of position: fixed because the fixed positioning might not work as expected within a 3D transformed context.

```
<div class="home-page-wrapper">
 <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <!-- Your content goes here -->
  </div>
</div>
    .home-page-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  perspective: 10px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('background-image.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(2);
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 65px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

By separating the background and content elements, you can control their positioning and styling independently, which may help resolve the issue you're encountering with the fixed positioning of the content.